# JSON formatting for iOS

Tags: ios, json, string-formatting

I've searched high and low, and can't decipher a solution. I'm trying to post a Json object to a local server which i've successfully achieved using terminal, however I'd like to send the object using objective-c within an iPhone app.

The template i'm using looks like the following:

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 NSString *postString = @"yourVarialbes=yourvalues";
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The Json object looks like this:

```
command={
          "ctl":{
                    "zone":"Office",
                    "component":"Yamaha RX A730",
                    "other":"Receiver",
                    "id":"1",
                    "service":"MEDIASERVER",
                    "command":"Play",
                    "arguments":{}
                 }
        }
```

Can anybody format the JSON object so that it fits into the template, or is it not that simple?

Cheers

Comment: Have you looked into using MKNetworkKit? http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Why recommend MKNetworkKit? The last commit was in December 2013, people who used it migrated to either AFNetworking or RestKit, depending what their needs of the project were.

Comment: @LyricalPanda - That was 9 months ago... it's not uncommon for Apple to go longer than that between framework updates and we don't call them dead so soon. As for AFNetworking or RestKit, those are each insanely heavy and complicated frameworks. I find MKNetworkKit to have a much smaller footprint and to be much easier to integrate into existing projects.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you need to use NSJSONSerialization convert JSON string to NSData.

```
+ dataWithJSONObject:options:error:
```